# Using an async function in another function

Tags: async-await, telethon

I'm trying to understand how to use an async function inside another function:

I'm trying to send messages via Telegram whenever something happens during my code.

**Telegram logger:**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
import asyncio

async def msgtelegram(entity, msg,api_id=xxx, api_hash='xx'):
    
    client = TelegramClient('Session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    
    if not await client.is_user_authorized(): 
        await client.sign_in('xxx')
   
    await client.send_message(entity, msg)


    await client.disconnect()

def func():
    try:
        print('hello!')
    except:
        await msgtelegram(entity, msg)
```

Calling await msgtelegram() outside of a function seems to work correctly.
Am I missing something or am I using async wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could use either [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) or [`loop.run_until_complete()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) so for your example it would be

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
import asyncio

async def msgtelegram(entity, msg,api_id=xxx, api_hash='xx'):
    
    client = TelegramClient('Session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    
    if not await client.is_user_authorized(): 
        await client.sign_in('xxx')
   
    await client.send_message(entity, msg)


    await client.disconnect()

def func():
    try:
        print('hello!')
    except:
        asyncio.run(msgtelegram(entity, msg))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try